# subdomain by registration creation

Tags: php, subdomain

I have and intention of creating sub domain by registration and be able to server other sub-domain on another server with the sub-domain created on my server.
My question is this:
1. How do I create a sub-domain authomatically with php scripts without accessing the cpanel at all and it will create a sub-folder of the sub-domain name inside the project folder while it is served the content of the main project? i.e

subdomain.domain.com
domain/public_html
---subdomain/
---index.html
2. How do I serve another sub-domain on another server with the content of the created the main project via the sub-domain i.e
another.server.com-----subdomain.domain.com

another.server.com is served with the content of domain.com

Comment: You'll want to look up how to make a "wildcard subdomain" in cPanel.

Comment: creating a wildcard subdomain without going through cpanel?  How can i do that?

Comment: You do it once in cPanel, and point the wildcard at a script that handles things accordingly. Or ditch cPanel entirely, as it takes over your server and leaves you limited ability to customize stuff.